# How to host sites on a single server?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I have five websites that I designed and now manage on a month-to-month basis. Currently, each website is hosted individually via HostGator. I am realizing this is the improper (and costly) way to manage multiple websites and am curious into how I could transfer the websites to a single server, and some hosts you guys find reliable.

Below is a snap of one of the sites usages, these are all static sites that are quite small. How much space would I need on my new, single server to accommodate 20 of these websites?

Current site usage:

http://imgur.com/18BvsC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image shows you are using 6.7 megabytes of data for one website.   If that is similar space usage for all 20 of your anticipated domains, you need virtually very little hosting space as far as storage goes these days.  Most entry level virtual hosting plans come with more than enough to meet your 20 domain expectations of like usage.

You want virtual hosting regardless.   Most web hosting providers have plans that allow you to host many domains, including hostgator.   Here is a link to compare their plans.  http://www.hostgator.com/shared-compare

I've used DreamHost and HostMonster in the past, with nothing bad to say about them.

Perhaps you should brush up more on the pros, cons and hows of web hosting.   Here is a link I just googled that might get you started.  http://www.webhostingsecretrevealed.net/web-hosting-beginner-guide/

Comment: Thanks a lot, all of the websites I am making on static pages for small businesses (i.e renovation company, bakery, window repair) with no dynamic user database. Sites with heavy data loads would have active, and growing user bases constantly interacting with the server? (uploading images, posts etc.)

Thanks a lot for the insight Eric.

Comment: @VegaStudios I think you'd find that even these virtual hosting plans can support even small business e-commerce site, or interactive wordpress, blogs, etc before needing to scale up to an individual plan for that client.